# How to validate if multiselect array is empty in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

How  can i validate if the multiselect array is empty?(fallos[]) heres my code :

```
<tr><td>Fallos reportados: </td><td><select name="fallos[]" size="6" multiple="multiple" >
    <?php 
    $query = "SELECT falla_id,falla FROM falla order by falla";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    echo "<option value=\"".$fila["falla_id"]."\">".$fila["falla"]."</option>";
}
    ?></td>
</tr>
```

and here is the validation that i´m making but doesn´t works

```
function validate(form) {
    fail  = validateIMEI(form.IMEI.value)
    fail += validateTelefono(form.numero_telefono.value)
    fail += validateICCID(form.ICCID.value)
    fail += validateFallos(form.fallos.value)
    if (fail === "") return true
    else { alert(fail); return false }

}
```

Here is the specific option that validates fallos[]:

```
function validateFallos(field) {
    if(field=== "") return "No se ha ingresado tipo de fallos"
    //if (field==="") return "No se han ingresado los tipos de fallos.\n"
    return ""
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
validateFallos(form.fallos.value)
```

`form` does not contain `fallos`. You have select element with name `fallos[]` that you can access by `form['fallos[]']` or more preferred `form.elements['fallos[]']`. If you want to stick with `form.fallos` you shoul add `id="fallos"` to your select tag.

Comment: +1 for spotting that _JavaScript_ doesn't recognise `[]` as having special meaning in a _name_ attribute. Following jsfiddle may be of interest http://jsfiddle.net/Rs3N3/

Comment: OK it works very fine with form.fallos.value when adding the id=fallos thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing semicolons at the end of your lines of code...

```
function validate(form) {
    fail  = validateIMEI(form.IMEI.value)
    fail += validateTelefono(form.numero_telefono.value)
    fail += validateICCID(form.ICCID.value)
    fail += validateFallos(form.fallos.value)
    if (fail === "") return true
    else { alert(fail); return false }
}
```

Should be

```
function validate(form) {
    fail  = validateIMEI(form.IMEI.value);
    fail += validateTelefono(form.numero_telefono.value);
    fail += validateICCID(form.ICCID.value);
    fail += validateFallos(form.fallos);
    if (fail === "") return true;
    else { alert(fail); return false; }
}
```

And also, the multiple select input would contain an array, so you can't just check to see if it's equal to `""`. Instead, loop through the array and check if any are selected, like so:

```
function validateFallos(fallosField) {
    var empty = true;
    for (i=0; i < fallosField.length; i++) {
        if (fallosField[i].selected) {
            return "";
        }
    }
    return "No se ha ingresado tipo de fallos";
}
```

Note how I changed `fail += validateFallos(form.fallos.value)` to `fail += validateFallos(form.fallos)`.

Comment: This looks like all you did is add semicolons `;`, which are optional (but preferred) in this context anyway.

Comment: Oh wow, how stupid of me - too much PHP! Forgot semicolons aren't compulsory in JS. Anyway, I updated my answer to give you a fix.

Comment: Only just realised that you aren't the OP. But yeah... I didn't spot that mistake :P